# Macro trigger math scope does not work in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I've recently changed my computer and did a TeXstudio install on top of a new Windows 10 install. When I tried importing my old TeXstudio Macros, I've stumbled on an odd problem.

My "math macros" triggers don't work anymore. The trigger defined with the scope limiting expression `(?highlighted-as:numbers,math-delimiter,math-keyword)` shown in the [documentation](https://fossies.org/linux/texstudio/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) doesn't work in any scope (math or otherwise). See image below.

When not using scope limiting expression (writing `A` instead of `(?highlighted-as:numbers,math-delimiter,math-keyword)A`) the macro is triggered. Strangely enough using `(?highlighted-as:comment,commentTodo)A` works just fine for comments.

I've tried restarting and also reinstalling TeXstudio. Nothing seems to work.

I've run TeXstudio 3.1.2 and also 3.1.1 on Windows 10. Back when I used TeXstudio 3.1.1 on Windows 7 I didn't have this problem.

Is there a solution to this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: FYI: I've removed the tag `{macros}` since it refers to TeX macros.

Comment: This is a bug, exists from ver. 3.x.
It looks no one working on it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following way worked:

- Declare the macro without `(?highlighted-as:numbers,math-delimiter,math-keyword)`
- Export the macro as `*.txsMacro`
- In any text editor edit the line with the trigger text to: `"trigger": "(?highlighted-as:numbers,math-delimiter,math-keyword)A` and save the file
- In TeXStudio import the Macro file.

Afterward, the macro is triggered only in Math modes.